# Como agregar prefijo en cada archivo

Tags: c#, powershell

Estoy buscando la manera mas facil de poder agregar un prefijo en cada archivo que tengo.

La situacion es que tengo archivos PDF los cuales se encuentran en varias sub carpetas, lo cual hace dificil el acceso. Pero estas sub carpetas pertenecen a una misma llamada reportes.

Lo que busco hacer es renombrar todo archivo terminado en .pdf y que inicie con "*". Cada archivo PDF tiene nombres unicos los cuales no son facil de identificar pero si cada uno de ellos deberia empezar con este "*".

Tambien me di cuenta que hay varios archivos PDF que ya empiezan con "_" y otros con una palabra.

Necesitaria agregar este prefijo solo en aquellos que empiezan de a-z o de 0-9.

Como podria hacer esto en powerShell, C# o alguno otro metodo?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias recorrer los archivos usando

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\carpeta", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach(string file in files)
{
    string fileNameIn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

    if(fileNameIn.StartsWith("_"))
        continue;

    string pathIn = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    string fileNameOut = string.Format("{0}_{1:yyyyMMdd}.pdf", fileNameIn, DateTime.Now);
    string pathOut = Path.Combine(pathIn, fileNameOut);

    File.Move(file, pathOut);
}
```

en este caso al encontrar los pdf los renombra realizando un `move` a la misma carpeta, solo que al nombre del archivo le agrego la fecha

Esto puede cambiarlo, es solo un ejemplo de como renombrar y seleccionar los archivos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He encontrado un problema. Ya edite la pregunta agregando estos detalles.
Hay algunos archivos que ya tienen "_" y otros con una palabra clave. No tengo que agregar el prefijo a estos archivos en cuestion

Comment: podrias seleccionarlos todos usando el *.pdf y despues cuendo iteras aplicas un if que valide que si inicia con _ o las palabras lo pase por alto

Comment: edite la respuesta, veras como se aplica el if para saltar ese archivo

Comment: Si bien entiendo, al poner continue; todo lo que este en el if lo pasara por alto y no lo aplicara para agregar el prefijo?

Comment: exacto, si se cumple el if ejecuta el continue volviendo al inicio del foreach

Comment: Ya veo el funcionamiento y me parece bien. Solo tengo una duda en la parte File.Move(file, pathOut); veo que hace un move. Lo que veo que duplica las carpetas y sus archivos. Podria remplazar los archivos existentes de las mismas carpetas envez de moverlos o copiarlos?
Hice el cambio cambiando por esto {0}.pdf ya que necesito que cada pdf agrege el _ al principio del archivo

Comment: El move se realiza a la misma carpeta donde estaba originalmente el archivo, ya que seria un rename, o sea solo cambias el nombre no lo cambias de carpeta. Podrias usar: string fileNameOut = string.Format("_{0}.pdf", fileNameIn);  de esta forma pones el _ al inicio del nombre

Comment: Sii!! muchas gracias. Me resulto todo bien. Gracias nuevamente